Reporting services not showing (http error 500)
I have a very strange issue. I have a server (OS 2022) with SSRS 2022 installed on it. The users are have a very strange issue, when they launch the URL of SSRS using a private navigation it is working fine but it is never working using "normal" navigation. We tried to clear cache and data from the browser setting, nothing changed. We are having this issue with both Chrome and EDGE.
I have checked the logs in SSRS server, nothing really relevant...
Here is the error we have:

Any idea, comment or something that I can do for this ?
Thank you,
Aniss

Explain what you mean by Private and Normal navigation?

Hi Alan, I'm talking about incognito mode (CTRL + Shift + N)

As this is not a specific programming question, it probably does not belong on this site, it might be better suited to another of the Stack Exchange sites such as https://serverfault.com/
